# Database design - Trackable and Dynamic Entity Fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine

I am creating a table to store data about a Person.

The requirements are as follows:

- Dynamic fields - each user may have different data fields stored for them. This needs to be built-in functionality without the need to add columns.
- Track changes - ability to track and revert changes to a specific point in time.
- Great performance
- MySQL

My idea currently is to have 2 tables, one to define the `Person` and the other to store `PersonData`. `PersonData` will reference `Person` and include a JSON field to store the data like
so

```
PID .... Date ....... Payload
1       1/1/2022     { name: 'John Smith', address: '1 Main St', state: 'NY' }
1       1/2/2022     { address: '5 Main St', state: 'CA' } ---Change address
1       1/3/2022     { phone: '888 777 6666' } ---Add phone
```

The result would be an object merge/replace on the rows with id: 1 resulting in:

```
{ name: 'John Smith', address: '5 Main St', state: 'CA', phone: '888 777 6666' }
```

My challenge is doing the array merge/replace cleanly and ideally natively in MySQL.

Is this a robust and elegant solution, or are the better ideas for how to implement this? I know there are other solutions like Mongo, but we want to keep this in Mysql.

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/

Answer (score 1):

Up-voting due to interest (mostly for the "ideally natively in MySQL" part).

Here is how I personally do it in production, if it can help or reassure you :

I have a "history" table :

[image]

I think an "event" column saves a lot of headaches. It holds events such as "created"/"updated"/"attached"/etc.
When an entry is "created", it looks like this :
[image]

When "updated", I hold changes with "before" and "after" keys in an array (json was introduced in MySQL 5.7.8+, I am below) :

[image]

This way I can print possibly complex edits in diffchecks/history pages in less than a few milliseconds, for any types (strings/integers/booleans) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How is this performace-wise. Like, what if there is a key called DOB, and you want a list of all persons in an organization (say 5,000) which their DOB. This means we have to load each users' WHOLE history, plus ALL columns (since all columns are stored in one json sting), then do some array manipulations to merge all the create/updates together to get the latest DOB. Isn't that super inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

After mulling this over for a year, here is what I'm leaning towards.

Would love feedback/critique.

`Person` table to track `Person`s.

`PersonData` table to track data. `Person` will point to latest `PersonData` record for that `Person`.

`PersonData` will include the *entirety* of the persons record. Meaning, each version will include ALL the data (not just the revisions). This will make it so that we don't have to query every version and combine them when doing a query.

`PersonData` will also keep some metadata on the record:

- Timestamp of record. This way, if we want to get the data as-of a certain time, we can easily find the relevant record.
- User who made the change that created this revision
- JSON PATCH to allow for "audit log" showing each revision: revision timestamp, revision user, and what changed.

When making changes to data, you need to simply copy the previous revision, make your change(s), create a JSON PATCH with the diff from the previous revision, INSERT the revision into the PersonData table, and update the `Person` to reference the most recent revision.

When querying the data, you simply need to join `Person` with `PersonData`.

H/T to this article: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-document-versioning-pattern